# plesk/nodejs server - email sent with no subject and no body

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer, plesk

I built NodeJS server on subdomain and was going to send email using email account of main domain.
Configuration settings with nodemailer is like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21i1n.png)

but whenever I call sendMail function, empty email is sent.
I am not sure what is the problem.
Please help me, is there anyone who has faced into similar issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodejs you can try with Nodemailer.
https://nodemailer.com/about/

```
Check out my code below, it is working with my Cpanel mail server.
    const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
    
    
    async function main() {
      
    
      
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "yoursmtp server.yourdomain",
        port: 465, 
        secure: true,
        auth: {
          user: "user", 
          pass: "password", 
        },
      });
    
      let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'youremail@yourdomain.com', 
        to: "example@hotmail.com",
        subject: "your subject", 
        text: "your body goes here ", 
       
      });
    
      console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
     
      console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    
    }
    
    main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes I use nodemailer and got above error when to call sendMail fundtion